# Is dp the same as dip?

Tags: android, dimensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference of px, dp, dip and sp in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

I've found several topics on this. But none really answers my question.

Dp and dip in android. What is the difference? Is it the same thing?

Comment: guess I didn't read carefully enough. Thanks for the down vote :)

Comment: This might be a duplicate but this is the first link that pops up on google when you find the difference between the 2

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. There is no difference, its just an alias.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension):

> The compiler accepts both "dip" and "dp", though "dp" is more consistent with "sp".

Comment: @LoungeKatt can you please explain a bit more? "dip" is not even mentioned in the documentation anymore and I have never seen anyone ever stating that there are "slight alteration of the size".